# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ht_4year_risk_opt' of null

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to to call the servlet which will return json data,but while parsing i' getting this error.

```
var jsondata = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
var ht_4year_risk_opt = jsondata.ht_4year_risk_opt;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tells you that `jQuery.parseJSON(data)` results in `null`. Two possible reasons for that:

1. It really is the string `"null"` (`jQuery.parseJSON("null")` returns `null`)
2. (Much more likely) `data` is `null`, which then `parseJSON` converts to the string `"null"` and then parses.  (`jQuery.parseJSON(null)` returns `null`)

So you'll want to find out why `data` is either `null` or `"null"`.